# $x^{a+b}-1$ is divisible by $x^{a}+mx^{b}+1$ for every positive integers $x$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $a, b, m$ be positive integers, $b$ is not divisible by $a$. Suppose that there exist a positive integer $x \geq 2$ such that $x^{a+b}-1$ is divisible by $x^{a}+mx^{b}+1$. Prove that it is also true for every positive integers $x$.

I think we can prove that $m=1$ then we have a simpler problem but i haven't proved that. and after that i do not know how to finish the problem.

Comment: any one help me? i still haven't solved

Comment: possible strategy: $x^{a+b} - 1 = (x^a + mx^b + 1) f(x)$.  This identity is probably true only if $b \nmid a$. So if it is true for any $x$, it is true for all $x$.

Comment: I still do not understand. Can you explain me why? And your solution?